# How can I access data from Variable Groups in dev ops using C#?

Tags: c#, azure-devops

[image]

I am using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable but getting null

var data = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("variableName");
Console.WriteLine(data);

I know I am missing something but don't know why. I want to use these variables in my code and not store them in a setting.json file

Comment: Can I suggest including some context in your question - what is it you want to do and why, what type of program are you trying to run, and where are you trying to run it from and how? How are you accessing the DevOps API, if at all, etc?

Comment: So I have some users and password which I want to use into my code from the variable groups,now I have those hardcoded in my code which I don't want anymore, so I want something like var data = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("username"); to get into code. I don't know how to access the devops api, I think that is my problem

Comment: right, but how is your application hosted, is there some pipeline deploying your application, is it using yaml or a classic pipeline?

Comment: using yaml. but what does that matter if I want to debug locally and access my variable groups and get what values I want from there?

Comment: I also use  using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                var _url = new UrlBuilder( "https:","dev.azure.com", $"{_organization}/{_project}/_apis/distributedtask/variablegroups/{_groupId}"
                .Url.ToString();
                var response = client.GetAsync(_url).Result;
                if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.OK)
                    return response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
                System.Console.WriteLine("Error");
                return null;
            }

Comment: I am getting an auth error, but if I use the link to chrome I can see my variables

Comment: I think I need an auth token but I don't know where to get it from azure dev ops

Answer (score 2):

> I want to use these variables in my code and not store them in a setting.json file

This is **not** the purpose of Azure DevOps variable groups. **Do not** try this approach.

Variable groups are intended to store pipeline configuration values and secrets, not application configuration. As an example of how this is an incorrect usage of variable groups, the REST APIs **do not** and **cannot** return secret values. Secret values are only available in pipelines.

You should use a real configuration store solution, such as Azure App Configuration in conjunction with Azure KeyVault.

Comment: Interesting that they provide all things to access the variable groups. Using a Get request with the auth and the id of the var groups you need and it will return all the data in that one.

Comment: @MacraAlexandru They provide REST APIs for managing variable groups just like they do for many other capabilities. That doesn't mean that variable groups are appropriate for storing runtime application configuration.